# Static linking of glibc in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks, glibc, static-linking

I want to do the static compilation of my code with glibc using codeblocks.For that , I have done the following ,
Project->Build Options->Linker settings->Other-linker-options , and then added -static-libgcc. And then build and the ran the code. The code was working fine in that Ubuntu-14.04 machine having glib version 2.19. Then I  copied the code to another machine having 2.12. The sole purpose of doing static linking was to make the code running in 2.12 as well. But it is giving the same error like that no static linking,as follows,
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
 /lib64/libc.so.6: version`GLIBC_2.14' not found
Can anybody please help me on this ? Am I doing the static linking of glibc correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glibc` is not `libgcc` (the GCC compiler support library). `glibc` is `libc` (the GNU C Library). `-static-libgcc` statically
links `libgcc`. You can't statically link `libc` except by statically
linking the entire executable, with `-static`.